# Moodle: Invalid login, please try again

Tags: php, mysql, apache, authentication, moodle

I'm migrating Moodle from one hosting to another but first I want to install it on my PC so I can use it as a reference guide. There's no way to check my old hosting files because the contract with them was already cancelled, I was recently hired for this job and it was a surprise.

I have a back up of everything they had (moodle and moodledata folders, database... but they didn't back up their courses, I only have folders and database). And now I want to install it on my computer (I want to have a reference of the contents and structure of the courses, etc).

I'm running Xampp, I copied the folders under htdocs, modified the config.php file to connect to the database and the page looks the same as the original, but the problem starts when I want to start my session with username and password, because Moodle no longer recognizes my login data. It's very weird, because I copied everything as it was in their old hosting.

I also have adapted the paths of directories and files for Windows in the config.php file, but still doesn't work. Does anyone know what might be happening? I'm attaching my config.php for you:

[config.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFHDC.jpg)

I should clarify that the version of Moodle I'm running is 2.6.11 (their hosting had PHP 5.3.29 and MySQL 5.1.73-cll and I tried running different versions of Wamp and Xampp with many different versions of PHP and MySQL). I know, it's terrible they didn't migrate before.

Comment: post actual code, 5th one already today

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy the password salt from the original system to your local config.php?